# On the prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p=q^2+q+1$ where p,q are prime numbers. Is it true that $p|(q−1)^2 (q^2+q)$?

MY TRY: 
I said that since $(p=q^2+q+1 , q^2+q)=1$, we have $p=q^2+q+1 \mid (q-1)^2$. Since $q^2+q+1  > (q-1)^2 $ , we get a contradiction, that is $p \nmid (q-1)^2 (q^2+q)$.
Now i want to know is it true?

Comment: Looks good. I think $q^{2}+q+1 > (q-1)^{2}$ to be precise. The equality need not hold :)

Comment: So is my proof true?

Comment: Yes, i think so!

Comment: As written the question is not clear; you have to read and understand the work to understand the question. It would be better if this was worded as something like "Let $p=q^2+q+1$ where $p, q$ are prime numbers. Is it true that $p|(q-1)^2(q^2+q)$?" And then the work.

Comment: Ok, i edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $p=q^2+q+1$ does not divide $(q-1)^2(q^2+q)$ even without the primality assumptions.  All we need to assume is that $q\gt1$.

If $(q-1)^2(q^2+q)=(q^2+q+1)k$, then $0\equiv k$ mod $q$, so $k=qh$ with $h\ge0$. This gives $(q-1)^2(q+1)=(q^2+q+1)h$, so $h\equiv1$ mod $q$, or $h=qr+1$ with $r\ge0$. Plugging this in leads to

$$(r-1)q^2+(r+2)q+(r+2)=0$$

which implies $r+2=qn$ with $n\gt0$.  Plugging *this* in leads to

$$nq^2+(n-3)q+n=0$$

The left hand side is clearly positive if $n\ge3$. For $n=2$, the quadratic $2q^2-q+2=0$ has no real roots.  And $q^2-2q+1=0$ has $q=1$ as its only solution.

There might be some easier way to organize the proof.  If so, I'd like to see it.

**Added later**:  Oh damn, Vidyanshu Mishra's answer simplifies things enormously.  The conclusion there that $p\mid3q$ does not depend on $p$ or $q$ being prime, and it immediately gives $3q=pn=(q^2+q+1)n$, or $nq^2+(n-3)q+n=0$.

Comment: Thanks dear Barry Cipra

Answer (score 4):

$q^2+q\equiv {-1} \pmod p $  and $p=(q-1)^2+3q\implies (q-1)^2\equiv {-3q}\pmod p$

Combining these two we get $p|3q$ and thus $p|q$ or $p|3$. Now former one is impossible since $p>q$ and latter being impossible as $p=3\implies q=1$.

Comment: My Pleasure @Hana

Answer (score 1):

HINT.- You can reduce your problem to just one prime because you have the question

$$\frac{q^3-1}{q-1}\space |\space(q-1)^2(q^2+1)$$ where $q$ is prime.

This way you can maybe be sure yourself of your good reasoning.

Comment: You are welcome, dear friend.(a way: divide the product $(q-1)^3(q^2+1)$ by $q^3-1$ ¿What do you get?)

Comment: Actually nothing! I cant use your hint.

Comment: The hint is simply that $\dfrac{q^3-1}{q-1}$ can not divide $(q-1)^2(q^2+1)$ for any prime $q$ so your result is correct.